# Easy way to use an UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

Does someone have an "easy way" to make a view like camera roll app? I need to display miniature  photos (buttons) and push new views from them. I don't know how to display miniature images in a scroll view. The number of miniatures is large, so they don't fit the screen, and I think UIScrollView is the only solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand this question. Could you edit and clarify, preferably without too many offtopic comments?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`TTThumbsViewController`](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_thumbs_view_controller.php), part of Three20; this should pretty much do what you want (and it's open source if you need to change it).

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thank you. But, anyway, I'd like something more easy and immediate. My first idea was to add a UIScrollView and put in it buttons (with the miniatures). Is this possible? Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know what's easier than code that already does what you want.  Of course, it's possible to do it as you say.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to "use" TTThumbsViewController. BTW, how to implement buttons with images in UIScrollView?

Comment: There's documentation on using Three20 including screencasts for getting started: http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project - I'm not going to write your code for you (especially when it's code that already exists), sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A scroll view really just controls the visible region of a single content view. If you want a grid of small images, you'll need to create a view that contains a number of image views or otherwise displays the grid of images. Make this the content view of the scroll view. Also, it'd be a good idea to construct your image grid view such that it only loads and draws the images that are visible, particularly if you're going to display a large number of such images.